# I sent my tokens to my token contract address

Tags: solidity, tokens

Can you please help me. This is my token with verified contract. I send 60% of the tokens to the token contract and I can’t get them back. Do you know a method how I can get tokens back? https://bscscan.com/token/0xc4f97ddaac9d7d68fe07c562931c7d12ef4921c8#balances

Comment: we need to see the code. by the way, it is not a "nft" contract, and the methods do not seem to follow the ERC20 or ERC777 either and looks also weird. Idk if there is a hide line of code that can transfer your tokens back to you

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code at https://bscscan.com/address/0xc4f97ddaac9d7d68fe07c562931c7d12ef4921c8#code , I'm afraid there is no way to get your tokens back. The contract simply doesn't have any such functionality.